# How could 45 milligrams of a substance equal 4,500 micrograms?

Tags: vitamins

In this book, the author repeatedly states that 45 milligrams of vitamin K2 equals 4,500 micrograms.  I thought 1 mg = 1000 mcg.  How could this be?

[image]

Comment: It's a typo. 1 mg = 1,000 mcg.

Comment: [Conversion tool](https://www.google.com/#q=1+mg+%3D+mcg).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivial question.

Comment: @AliceD, It's only trivial if you have a certain amount of experience.  With vitamins and "nutraceuticals", I've seen errors caused by conflating and mislabeling between "mg", "mcg", and "Mg" (where "Mg" was perversely meant to be convey micrograms!) .  This is so serious that [the FDA has repeatedly warned about it](http://www.fda.gov/AnimalVeterinary/ResourcesforYou/ucm214772.htm)

Comment: @BrockAdams - you may be right, but then again I doubt this is the right forum for these matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typo.  In the text he states:

> ... only 0.120 milligrams (120 micrograms) of MK-4 ...

So, he knows the correct conversion.

Then:

> ... the "same" product is almost 40 times more potent in one country
>   ...

40 times 120 micrograms is 4800 micrograms -- which is close to 4500.

So, that suggests that **the `(4,500 micrograms)` in the table is correct** and that the `45 milligrams` is a typo.

**It should read `4.5 milligrams`.**